# What is __NSCFData and how does it relate to NSData?

Tags: ios

I got the following error in iOS and wasn't able to come up with a good idea of what **`__NSCFData`** is.  I understand why the error is occurring and we've fixed the issue, but I was curious about the unfamiliar class that showed up in the error message.

```
2017-08-07 21:41:37.458 [**App name redacted**][5316:2314238]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFData isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent
to instance 0x6080000b97b0'
```

I read through the docs on [`NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata), [`CFData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfdata-rv9), and [toll-free bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH2)

I've also looked at the header for [`__NSCFData`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/__NSCFData.h) and it's a subclass of `NSImmutableData`.  There's also an [`NSCFData`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/NSCFData.h) class as well, which confused me.

I had the following questions:

1. What is the double underscore in `__NSCFData` for?
2. What exactly is `NSCFData`? Perhaps it's an ambiguous type that could refer to either an `NSData` or `CFData` object?

Comment: It is part of the NSData class cluster. Why do you need to know what it is beyond that?  Your code crashed because you are calling an NSString method on an instance of NSData.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, this is more out of curiosity.  I know the reason why the crash is occurring.  I expected to see NSData or CFDataRef  in the error log instead of a private __NSCFData class and was wondering what that was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Foundation types and corresponding CoreFoundation types are "toll-free bridged" to each other, which means that the internal layout of the CoreFoundation structs are identical to that of an Objective-C object, the result being that toll-free bridged NS and CF types can be simply cast to each other without having to go through any conversion process. `NSData` and `CFDataRef` are an example of types that are bridged in this way; you can take a `CFDataRef` from plain C, cast it to an `NSData *`, and use it as an Objective-C object, and it will work.

Of course, there is a lot of hackery going on under the hood to enable all this magic, including many private types such as `__NSCFData`. These are generally implementation details that you don't need to worry about; the part that is relevant is that your object belongs to a subclass of `NSData`, and thus you can use `NSData`'s methods on it (and not `NSString`'s; the error message you've posted suggests something in your code is trying to send `NSString`'s `-isEqualToString:` method to an `NSData` object, which is not valid).

Anyway, to figure out what code is trying to send the wrong message to an `NSData` object, set an exception breakpoint in the debugger, and that should turn it right up as soon as your program hits the error.